# How to use a variable in v-model or :value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using v-model within a component and I want to dynamically update the v-model to point to an object.

I have a component which is a form and I want to use v-model or :value to prefill the inputs.

I am inserting the data via a prop and I am getting the `childId` from a click event and then using the info to populate them like so. ie: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="child_name" v-model="children.child1.name">`

I need to change `child_1` to a variable so it could be child_1 or 2 or 3 or 4. I've tried replacing it with a string variable which breaks to flow. Any ideas how to solve this issue? I've often used variables in Vue before but never for v-model or value.

I am using this sample data:

```
childId: child_1

  children: {
      child_1: {
        id: 'child_1',
        name: 'Ruth Ann Morgan',
        gender: 'female',
        birth_year: '1999',
        parentage: 'our_child',
        dependency: 'not_dependent'
      },
      child_2: {
        id: 'child_2',
        name: 'James Nico Morgan',
        gender: 'male',
        birth_year: '2012',
        parentage: 'our_child',
        dependency: 'is_dependent'
      }
  },
```

Comment: Do you define a data variable call `childId` and passing `v-model="children[childId].name"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
v-model="children[childId].name"
```

Just make sure that `childId` equals a valid key in the `children` object otherwise you'll get an error.